# What statistical test do I use for 2 IV's and 3DV's?

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis, manova

I'm trying to find out whether personality (tetrad) effects sexual fantasy, sexual behaviour and sexual attitudes. In addition I want to find out whether gender has an effect on all of this. What statistical analyses should I use? I'm not sure whether it's MANOVA or multivariate multiple regression????

Comment: More details are needed on the design, scaling of variable(s), hypotheses to be tested, etc. The simplest and easiest approach: fit a linear regression for each outcome, report the slope, report the significance rate for the test of interaction with gender. Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of research question might be answered with a descriptive disciminant analysis (DDA), which is a type of multivariate ananysis of variance (manova). See Tabachnick & Fidell (2013) for a great walk-through of DDA. For what it's worth, I've never heard of 'multivariate miltiple regression.'

EDIT: I see, I think what you call a 'multivariate multiple regression' is what I call a factorial manova. To do this in SPSS:

```
GLM x y by a b
/METHOD=SSTYPE(3)
/INTERCEPT=INCLUDE
/PRINT=DESCRIPTIVE TEST(SSCP) HOMOGENEITY
/CRITERIA=ALPHA(.05)
/DESIGN=a b a*b

DISCRIMINANT
/GROUPS=a(1 2)
/VARIABLES= x y
/ANALYSIS ALL
/PRIORS EQUAL
/STATISTICS=MEAN STDEV UNIVF BOXM CORR COV GCOV TCOV
/CLASSIFY=NONMISSING POOLED.
```

Look at homogeneity of variance-covariance matrices (Box's M and Log determinants), calculate 1-Wilks' Lambda, interpret standardized coefficients and structure coefficients, and calculate cohen's d between groups. If 1-Wilks' Lambda is small, nothing else matters.

Comment: Multivariate multiple regression is used when you have two or more dependent variables that are to be predicted from two or more independent variables, but I'm not sure how it differs from a MANOVA and out of the two which would suit best. I'm not sure what DDA is?

Comment: DDA is a technique that shows if being in a group can predict differences in variables. In other words, the group is your IV and the variables are your DVs. I suspect your concept of 'multivariate multiple regression' is not at all different from manova. If you can say more about the software you are using or even post reproducible data I can try to help more.

Comment: the software I'm using is SPSS, I'm interested in finding out the relationship between the Iv's and Dv's as well as within the Dv's themselves. Multivariate regression and Manova like you said are very similar. This was a questionnaire design, where all participants voluntarily completed an online questionnaire.

Comment: @K.K I have edited my answer above with appropriate SPSS syntax. Notice that the variables and design are fillers. There is a procedure you should follow when doing DDA that requires practice, so you might want to look at the book chapter by Tabachnick and Fidell (2013) as I mentioned in my comment.